# Multiple type parameters - constrain to same base class?

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

Let's say we have this class structure:

```
interface A { }
interface A1 : A { }
interface A2 : A { }
class B : A1 { }
class C : A1 { }
class D : A2 { }
class E : A2 { }
```

And I want to declare a method with this header:

```
public void DoSomething<T, U>()
    where T : A
    where U : A
    <and also where U inherits/implements same parent as T>
```

It needs to allow `DoSomething<B, C>()`:

- `where T : A` is satisfied - `B` implements `A`
- `where U : A` is satisfied - `C` implements `A`
- `<and also where U inherits/implements same parent as T>` is satisfied because both `B` and `C` implement `A1`
- `DoSomething<D, E>()` is also allowed because `D` and `E` both implement `A2`

But it needs to not allow `DoSomething<B, D>()`:

- `where T : A` is satisfied - `B` implements `A`
- `where U : A` is satisfied - `C` implements `A`
- `<and also where U inherits/implements same thing as T>` is **not satisfied** because `B` implements `A1` but D does not.

Is this possible?

(I think I've butchered the use of the word 'parent' there, but hopefully it's still clear)

Comment: If it needs to allow `B, C` and not `B, D` why not `where T : A1 where U : A1`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov edited question slightly for clarity - it would also need to allow `DoSomething<D, E>()` because `D` and `E` both implement `A2`

Comment: You could create two overloads of the method. Once accepting `A1` and one accepting `A2`.

Comment: Why not do `where T : A` and `where U : T`?

Comment: @Luaan He doesn't want to allow pairs such as `A1` and `A2`. `A` is too big.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If it's possible, I'd like to avoid doing one method per parent, seems like it would be cleaner and more maintainable (if `A3`, `A4`, ... `A400` are created in future) if it can be done in one method. My grant total experience with generics is about 2 hours, so if I'm barking up *entirely* the wrong tree here I wouldn't be too surprised!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It doesn't allow that - `U` will be constrained by the *actual* type of `T`, not by `A`. It will always have to use those interfaces, though, not the actual classes - but there really isn't any way around this without dynamic dispatch. The problem is you can't exclude the *actual* type of `T` and only constrain to the *base* types, so `DoSomething<B, C>` will not work. But really, that can't be solved by generics alone, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to add some more information about the ideas behind your implementation? This could quite easily be an XY problem; what are you actually trying to solve underneath?

Comment: So, `<B,D>` should not be allowed because they're direct descendants of `A1` and `A2`, even though they do have a common interface - `A`. Any reason why you need this kind of restriction? it seems very odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to provide a third generic type parameter that will let you specify which interface both `T` and `U` have to implement:

```
public void DoSomething<T, U, V>()
    where T : V
    where U : V
    where V : A
```

Now you can do `DoSomething<D, E, A1>()` but not `DoSomething<B, D, A1>()`.